# Unable to Get Gender For Most Google Accounts with Google Sign In

Tags: android, google-signin, google-api-java-client, google-apis-explorer

I have tried almost every solution available on the internet, but Google Sign-In never seems to return "Gender" values for most of the Google Accounts. Gender value is returned in just a few cases where the user has a Google+ Profile and has manually marked it as Public.

Is there any simple way to get user's gender(with/without requesting user about it) with Google SignIn??? (Something as simple as Facebook Sign in)

Has anyone on stackoverflow been successful in doing it ??

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it's a quite an easy task to retrieve gender with Google API.
No matter what you program on. Pity that Google ignores Perl I'm in love with for many years.
When you done all the steps to getting access_token it's a piece of cake to get gender:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=

JSON reply you get will contain 'gender' field.